# Collision not working, causes UFO object to bounce

Tags: python, pygame

for context, this is for a college assignment, so I am attempting to change the base code as little as possible

This is pretty much a replica of a 'space invader' game and the assignment paper has asked me to activate an explosion on collision of the UFO with a bullet, however, I'm running into problems:

1. The bullet only shoots when holding down the Arrow Up Key, but I would like the bullet to shoot when the Arrow Up Key is pressed once, like the standard shoot mechanic
2. The UFO bounces to the other side of the screen when the bullet reaches .y 0, and never 'explodes' on collision

This is the code:

```
import pygame
import random
import math

# credit to "bart" from opengameart.org for the following assets:
# bullet_1.png
# explos_1.png
# explos_2.png
# explos_3.png
# explos_4.png
# spaceship_1.png
# spaceship_2.png
# ufo_1.png
# link to assets: https://opengameart.org/content/i-are-spaceship-16x16-space-sprites

# credit to "astrellon3" from reddit for the following assets:
# bg.png
# link to assets: https://www.reddit.com/r/PixelArt/comments/f1wg26/space_background/

class Rocket():
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.image = pygame.image.load('assets/spaceship_1.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

class UFO():
    def __init__(self, screen):
        super(UFO, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.speed = [5, 5]
        self.image = pygame.image.load('assets/ufo_1.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randint(100, 600)
        self.rect.y = random.randint(100, 600)
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.ufo_X_pos = self.rect.centerx
        self.ufo_Y_pos = self.rect.centery

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def move(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(self.speed)  # ufo_rect.move_ip (x, y)
        self.ufo_X_dir = 0
        self.ufo_Y_dir = 0
        self.ufo_X_pos = 0
        self.ufo_Y_pos = 0
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.speed[0] = -self.speed[0]
            self.ufo_X_dir = self.ufo_X_dir - 1
        if self.rect.right > 600:
            self.speed[0] = -self.speed[0]
            self.ufo_X_dir = self.ufo_X_dir + 1
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.speed[1] = -self.speed[1]
            self.ufo_Y_dir = self.ufo_Y_dir - 1
        if self.rect.bottom > 600:
            self.speed[1] = -self.speed[1]
            self.ufo_Y_dir = self.ufo_Y_dir + 1

class Bullet():
    def __init__(self, screen, rocket):
        self.screen = screen
        self.image = pygame.image.load('assets/bullet_1.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rocket = rocket
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = self.rect.centerx
        self.y = 600
        self.state = 'nofire'

    def draw(self):
        # Draw the ufo at its current location.
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def fire(self, rocketxpos):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, (rocketxpos, self.y))
        self.y -= 10
        if self.y < 0:
            self.state = 'nofire'
            self.y = 600

    #def update(self):
        #self.y -= 10

    def isCollision(self, ufo):
        distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(ufo.ufo_X_pos - self.x, 2) + (math.pow(ufo.ufo_Y_pos - self.y, 2)))
        if distance < 35:
            return True
        else:
            return False

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
running = 1
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 25)
background = pygame.image.load("assets/bg.png").convert()
exp = pygame.image.load("assets/explos_1.png").convert_alpha()

rocket = Rocket(screen)

ufo = UFO(screen)
ufo2 = UFO(screen)

bullet = Bullet(screen, rocket)

while running:
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = 0
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                rocket.rect.centerx += 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                rocket.rect.centerx -= 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                bullet.fire(rocket.rect.centerx)

    rocket.draw()

    #bullet.update()

    ufo.draw()
    ufo.move()



    if bullet.isCollision(ufo) == True:
        ufo.rect.x = random.randint(0, 736)
        ufo.rect.y = random.randint(50, 300)
        screen.blit(exp, (ufo.rect.x, ufo.rect.y))
        # show explosion image

    clock.tick(25)
    pygame.display.update()
```

As seen in commented code, I have tried to implement an update function for the bullet, however, that did not work.

I am completely stuck with the collision method as well since I *know* they want me to stick with the distance equation, so using pygame's inbuilt collision function is a no-go

(If I'm being honest, I don't like how they programmed this at all, but I'm forced to deal with it)

Any suggestions are appreciated!!!